# Thread safety on child object when setter is on parent

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Will the following example code be threadsafe in a mulithread environment,  when creating a new Child object
where some setters are on the parent.

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
   private String familyName;

   public Strng getFamily() {
     return familyName;
   }
   public void setFamily (String familyName) {
    return  this.familyName = familyName
}
```

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass  {
   private String firstName;

   public String getFirstName() {
     return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName (String firstName) {
    return  this.firstName = firstName
}
```

Now, when i Create a new Child as below shown below, will the setter (setFamily) be thread safe when the child object is proccesed in the application

```
var child = new ChildClass()
child.setFirstName("Jo");
child.setFamilyName("Smith");
```

Comment: Inheritance has nothing to do with thread safety. What exactly do you mean by "thread safe"?

Comment: Since there's no path-dependent variation in execution, there's nothing to 'go wrong' in this code. At least, not if assigning a reference is atomic in the JVM, which I think it is.

Comment: Your Question could be improved by editing the body to explain a bit about whatever concern prompted you to write this post.

Answer (score 0):

[Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) and [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) are orthogonal topics.

This code:

```java
var child = new ChildClass()
child.setFirstName("Jo");
child.setFamilyName("Smith");
```

… is thread-safe if all three lines execute within the same thread.

Thread-safety issues arise from shared resources. Such resources include a shared file possibly being modified, a shared network connection, or a shared [mutable variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Immutable_variables).

In this case, you have a new instance of `ChildClass`. Being new means it is, so far, unshared with any other thread. You access its contained fields via setter methods on that same instance within the same thread — so no other threads means no resources shared across threads, and that means no thread-safety issues.

The fact that two setters are defined on the subclass while another setter is defined on the superclass does not affect thread-safety. You can think of those two classes as being coalesced, with the superclass content collapsed into the subclass.

As far as thread-safety goes, there is no difference between a single class defining all three setters and a pair of classes where one defines two setters and the other defines a single setter.

If you start calling those getters and setters from across threads, then you will have thread-safety problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
var child = new ChildClass()
child.setFirstName("Jo");
child.setFamilyName("Smith");
```

Technically, those lines are thread-safe because the object that `child` refers to is *thread confined*; i.e. it is only accessible from one thread.

And if another thread *could* access the `child` instance, then the application as a whole would not be thread-safe.  (There are some complicated exceptions to this, but lets not go there.)

However, the classes themselves are NOT thread-safe.  The location of the methods in the superclass or subclass makes no difference to thread safety.  If you want those classes to be unconditionally thread-safe, then you need to add some explicit synchronization mechanism, OR rewrite them to be immutable classes.

---

Note that thread-safety is technically difficult to define in precise terms.  One approach is to start with some code that is functionally correct (per some specified requirements) when executed with only one thread.  If the code is *also* functionally correct for *all possible executions* involving more than one thread, then the code is thread safe.

So if we are going to ask the question is class `XYZ` thread safe, we first need a specification that `XYZ` needs to meet.  In your example classes, we can infer a specification that says that the getters return the values most recently set by the corresponding setters.  Your classes are NOT thread-safe per that specification because the lack of synchronization means that there can be memory anomalies.  But declaring the getters and setters as `synchronized` methods would be sufficient for thread-safety with respect to that spec.

Answer (score -1):

No, both the classes are not thread safe.
You have to use synchronisation mechanism to achieve thread safety.

1. You can use synchronized keyword in the parent class's getter and setter.
2. Or you can use other synchronisation mechanism to achieve the thread safety like ReentrantLock or Semaphores.

Can you please elaborate more on this?

Just putting a sample code, to achieve thread safety using semaphores.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public abstract class ParentClass {
  private String familyName;
  private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1); // Initialize with one permit

  public String getFamily() {
    return familyName;
  }

  public void setFamily(String familyName) {
    try {
        semaphore.acquire(); // Acquire the permit
        this.familyName = familyName;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        semaphore.release(); // Release the permit
    }
  }
 }

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  private String firstName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

This ensures that only one thread can modify the familyName at a time, making it thread-safe.